# Setting min and max number of selections in a multiple box

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

I'm trying to set min and max selection values for a multiple select box.

I've seen something similar done for a radio button list (only for max value) here
http://jsfiddle.net/rREfg/1/

```
var maxCheckedCount = 5;
var maxCheckedAlertMessage = 'Woops! Too many selected!';

    jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
        var n = jQuery('input:checked').length;
        if(n>=maxCheckedCount){
            jQuery(this).prop('checked',false);
            alert(maxCheckedAlertMessage);
        }
    });
```

Now if this is my new html

```
<select multiple size=7>
    <option value="1">Strawberry</option>
    <option value="2">Prune</option>
    <option value="3">Lemon</option>
    <option value="4">Peach</option>
    <option value="5">Apple</option>
    <option value="6">Banana</option>
    <option value="7">Orange</option>
</select>
```

How can I adjust the code to get min selection 2 items and max selection 5 items?

Comment: The size attribute changes how many items are visible, not how many can be selected. --- On second thought, I don't think you implied that...

Comment: like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/rREfg/20/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it like this

**HTML**

```
<select multiple size=7>
   <option value="1">Strawberry</option>
   <option value="2">Prune</option>
   <option value="3">Lemon</option>
   <option value="4">Peach</option>
   <option value="5">Apple</option>
   <option value="6">Banana</option>
   <option value="7">Orange</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
var maxCheckedCount = 5;
var maxCheckedAlertMessage = 'Woops! Too many selected!';

jQuery('select').change(function(event) {
    var n = $(this).children(':selected').length;
    if(n >= maxCheckedCount){
        $(this).children().prop('selected',false);
        alert(maxCheckedAlertMessage);
        return false;
    }
});
jQuery('.checkValid').click(function()
{
    if($('select').children(':selected').length <= 2) {
       alert('Keep Adding');
       return false;
    }
});
```

```js
var maxCheckedCount = 5;
    var maxCheckedAlertMessage = 'Woops! Too many selected!';

        jQuery('select').change(function(event) {
            var n = $(this).children(':selected').length;
            if(n >= maxCheckedCount){
                $(this).children().prop('selected',false);
                alert(maxCheckedAlertMessage);
                n = maxCheckedCount;
                return false;
            }
        });
        jQuery('.checkValid').click(function()
        {
           if($('select').children(':selected').length <= 2) {
              alert('Keep Adding');
              return false;
           }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple size=7>
    <option value="1">Strawberry</option>
    <option value="2">Prune</option>
    <option value="3">Lemon</option>
    <option value="4">Peach</option>
    <option value="5">Apple</option>
    <option value="6">Banana</option>
    <option value="7">Orange</option>
</select>
<button class='checkValid'>Clike Me!</button>
```

Comment: how about the minimum selection?

Comment: @JMS786 in his given snippet there is a only for max. and minimum selection will not done by from here. it will be done when he validate this select on any button click or form submission

Comment: @kiltro You can add 1 button for validation. let me give you example

Comment: That's great! Thanks

Comment: @kiltro Than Please accept answer. it will also helpful to me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/9k1sgbjz/1/

```js
var selectedOption = [];
$('select option').click(function(){
 var index = selectedOption.indexOf($(this).text());
 if( index < 0){
   // insert
    selectedOption.push($(this).text());
  }else{
   // remove
    selectedOption.splice(index, 1);
  }
  if( selectedOption.length < 2 || selectedOption.length === 5){
   $('button').prop('disabled', true);
  }else{
   $('button').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple size=7>
    <option value="1">Strawberry</option>
    <option value="2">Prune</option>
    <option value="3">Lemon</option>
    <option value="4">Peach</option>
    <option value="5">Apple</option>
    <option value="6">Banana</option>
    <option value="7">Orange</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" disabled>
Submit
</button>
```

Instead of **alert** or **console**, I just **enable/disable** a **button** i.e. present below.